# ClassLoder.getResourceAsStream()で.propertiesファイルを読み込めず、Nullになる

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

#### 発生している問題

---

Eclipseで作成した、Maven webappプロジェクトの、`src/test/resources`ディレクトリにある、`.properties`ファイルを`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`で読み込みたいのですが、'NullPointer' で読み込めません。

#### 試したこと

---

pom.xmlかパスの表記に問題があるのではないかと思い色々調べて試しましたが、
どれもnullになります。

実効pomのtestResourceが
${basedir}/upload_image_db4/src/main/resources
なので、
getResourceAsStream（"/jdbc/JdbcDataSource_H2.properties"）と考えていますが誤りでしょうか。

基本的な部分で間違っているような気がするので、「よくある間違い」的な小さなヒントで構いません。
何か情報をいただけると幸いです。

宜しく御願い致します。

---

**ディレクトリ**

```
src
  |-main
  |-test
     |---java 
           -testModel
              GetDataSourceLogic.java


     |---resources
          -jdbc
              JdbcDataSource_H2.properties
```

#### エラーメッセージ

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.model.logic.RegisterLogicTest2.<clinit>(RegisterLogicTest2.java:35)
    ... 55 more
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
public class GetDataSourceLogic{
        public JdbcDataSource getH2DataSource() throws IOException{

            Properties props = new Properties();
            JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
            try(InputStream in=ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/jdbc/JdbcDataSource_H2.properties")){
                props.load(in);
                dataSource.setURL(props.getProperty("JDBC_URL"));
                dataSource.setUser(props.getProperty("USER"));
                dataSource.setPassword(props.getProperty("PASSWORD"));


            return dataSource;

        }
```

**Ecilpseの実効pom**　　(抜粋)

```
  <build>
   : 
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/Applications/Eclipse_2019-03.app/Contents/upload_image_db4/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
   :
   :
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.5</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>add-test-source</id>
              <phase>process-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <sources>
                  <source>/Applications/Eclipse_2019-03.app/Contents/upload_image_db4/src/test/resources</source>
                </sources>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
    :
```

**JdbcDataSource_H2.properties**

```
#H2 JDBC
JDBC_DRIVER=org.h2.Driver.class.getName();
JDBC_URL=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
USER=sa
PASSWORD=
```

#### 補足情報

Eclipse 4.11.0
Maven 3

Comment: なぜ標準的な方法（`ResourceBundle`）を使わずに、`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`を使うのでしょうか？

Comment: [APIドキュメント](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)を見ると明らかですが、これはリソースバンドルではありません(ロケール固有のオブジェクトが含まれるような性質のものではありません)。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、質問文中で使用しているメソッド

```
ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(...)
```

は [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) でなく [`Class#getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)です。

次に、`ClassLoader`はJDKに含まれるクラスであり、

> このメソッドは、このオブジェクトのクラス・ローダーに委譲されます。このオブジェクトがブートストラップ・クラス・ローダーによってロードされた場合、このメソッドはClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)に委任します。

に該当し、結果、システムリソースを検索しようとしている実装になっています。

代わりに次を用います:

```
GetDataSourceLogic.class
.getResourceAsStream("/jdbc/JdbcDataSource_H2.properties")
```

あるいは

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
.getResourceAsStream("jdbc/JdbcDataSource_H2.properties")
```

いずれの場合も、 `getResource("")` メソッド(引数に空文字列を与える)の戻り値を見ればどこを指しているのか理解できるかと思います。

Comment: 御丁寧に回答いただいていたにも関わらず、コメントが遅くなり申し訳ありませんでした。直に代入する方法で対応していたのでこの問題をしばらく放置していた為、いただいたコメントに気付くのが遅れました。

Comment: ClassLoaderのあたりは、まだまだですが理解したいところだったので大変参考になりました。現状、source codeはそのままですが、Logicを書き換えJUnitで確認したところNullが解消されました。本当に有難う御座いました。