# WildFlyでwarフォルダ下のファイルを読み込む方法

Tags: wildfly

Linux環境下でWildFly18.0.1を使用しています。

warフォルダのWEB-INF/classes/下にtest.txtというのがあります。
ブラウザ上で特定のボタンを押すとtest.txtというファイルの中身を読み込んで画面上に表示させたいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [ClassLoder.getResourceAsStream()で.propertiesファイルを読み込めず、Nullになる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57822/classloder-getresourceasstream%e3%81%a7-properties%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%82%92%e8%aa%ad%e3%81%bf%e8%be%bc%e3%82%81%e3%81%9a-null%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b)

Answer (score 0):

```java
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
```

で `InputStream` 型として取得できます。